# What are FromJSON1 and ToJSON1 used for in aeson?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, aeson, higher-kinded-types

Aeson provides [`FromJSON1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.3.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:FromJSON1) and [`ToJSON1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.3.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:ToJSON1) type classes.  These are similar to the [`Eq1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Classes.html#t:Eq1) and [`Show1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Classes.html#t:Show1) classes defined in the [`Data.Functor.Classes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Classes.html) module.

My understanding of the `Eq1` and `Show1` classes is that they are needed to be able to express constraints on arguments of transformers without using extensions like `FlexibleContexts` and `UndecidableInstances`.

The example from the documentation in the `Data.Functor.Classes` module is as follows:

Assume we have a data type that acts as a transformer: `T`.  For an example, let's have it be isomorphic to `IdentityT`:

```
data T f a = T (f a)
```

The kind of `T` is as follows:

```
T :: (* -> *) -> * -> *
```

If there is an `Eq1` instance for `f`, it is possible to use it when writing the `Eq1` instance for `T f`:

```
instance Eq1 f => Eq1 (T f) where
  liftEq :: (a -> b -> Bool) -> T f a -> T f b -> Bool
  liftEq eq (T fa1) (T fa2) = liftEq eq fa1 fa2
```

If we have an `Eq1` instance for `f`, an `Eq` instance for `a`, and the `Eq1` instance for `T f` above is in scope, we can easily write the `Eq` instance for `T f a`:

```
instance (Eq1 f, Eq a) => Eq (T f a) where
  (==) :: T f a -> T f a -> Bool
  (==) = eq1
```

The type of `eq1` is defined as follows:

```
eq1 :: (Eq1 h, Eq a) => h a -> h a -> Bool
```

In our instance above, `h` becomes `T f`, so the type of `eq1` can be thought of as the following:

```
eq1 :: Eq a => T f a -> T f a -> Bool
```

---

Now, the `Eq1`, `Show1`, etc classes make sense.  It seems like it makes it easier to write instances of `Eq`, `Show`, etc for transformers.

However, I'm wondering what types `FromJSON1` and `ToJSON1` are used for in Aeson?  I rarely have transformers that I want to turn to and from JSON.

Most of the data types I end up changing to JSON are normal types (not type constructors).  That is to say, types with the kind `*`.  I also uses types like `Maybe` with a kind of `* -> *`.

However, I don't think I often create `ToJSON` or `FromJSON` instances for transformers, like the `T` above.  What is a transformer that is often used to go to and from JSON?  Am I missing out on some helpful transformers?

Comment: Those classes were introduced through [*aeson* issue #352](https://github.com/bos/aeson/issues/352). There might be a good answer to be extracted from the discussion there (and in the related [issue #341](https://github.com/bos/aeson/pull/341)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Eq1` offers another feature that you haven't discussed in your exposition: it lets you write a function that calls `(==)` at many different types, without necessarily knowing ahead of time which types you will use it on.

I'll give a toy example; hopefully you can see through the apparent uselessness of this example to the reason `Eq1` gives you some interesting powers.

Imagine you want to make a tree that is parameterized on the branching factor, so you parameterize it by the child container. So values might look like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data Tree m a where
    Branch :: Tree m (m a) -> Tree m a
    Leaf :: a -> Tree m a
```

For example, I can get binary trees with `Tree Pair`, trinary trees with `Tree Triple`, finger trees with `Tree TwoThree`, and rose trees with `Tree []`, where `data Pair a = Pair a a`, `data Triple a = Triple a a a`, and `data TwoThree a = Two a a | Three a a a`. Now I would like to write an `Eq` instance for this. If we only rely on `Eq` constraints, we can't get where we want to go. Let's try:

```
instance Eq (Tree m a) where
    Leaf a == Leaf a' = a == a'
    Branch t == Branch t' = t == t'
    _ == _ = False
```

Naturally, GHC complains that it doesn't know how to compare `a` and `a'` for equality. So add `Eq a` to the context:

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Tree m a) where ...
```

Now GHC complains that it doesn't know how to compare `m a`s for equality in the `Branch` case. Makes sense.

```
instance (Eq a, Eq (m a)) => Eq (Tree m a) where ...
```

Still no go! Now the implementation of `(==) :: Tree m a -> Tree m a -> Bool` has a recursive call to `(==) :: Tree m (m a) -> Tree m (m a) -> Bool` in its `Branch` case, hence must provide the context `(Eq (m a), Eq (m (m a)))` to make that recursive call. Okay, let's add that to the instance context...

```
instance (Eq a, Eq (m a), Eq (m (m a))) => Eq (Tree m a) where ...
```

Still no good. Now the recursive call has to prove even more stuff! What we'd really like to say is that if we have `Eq b`, then we have `Eq (m b)`, for all `b`s and not just for the specific `a` being used as `Tree`'s second parameter.

```
instance (Eq a, (forall b. Eq b => Eq (m b))) => Eq (Tree m a) where ...
```

Of course that's totally not a thing in Haskell. But `Eq1` gives us that:

```
instance Eq1 m => Eq1 (Tree m) where
    liftEq (==) (Leaf a) (Leaf a') = a == a'
    liftEq (==) (Branch t) (Branch t') = liftEq (liftEq (==)) t t'
    liftEq (==) _ _ = False

instance (Eq1 m, Eq a) => Eq (Tree m a) where
    (==) = eq1
```

Here the `Eq1 m` constraint is serving the role we asked for before, namely, that all of `(Eq a, Eq (m a), Eq (m (m a)), ...)` are possible.

The `ToJSON1` and `FromJSON1` classes serve a similar role: they give you a single constraint that you can give that amounts to a potentially infinite collection of `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` constraints, so that you can choose which `ToJSON` or `FromJSON` constraint you need in a data-driven way and be guaranteed that it's available.

Comment: Thanks!  This is a really nice explanation.  I'm going to have to go through this slowly to really let it sink in.  In my own code I don't think I tend to use recursive types that pack on more and more type constructors (like `data Tree m a = Branch (Tree m (m a))`).  I'll have to keep my eyes open for places when that will be useful.  Also, will `Eq (Tree m a)` be possible to write now with [quantified constraints](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/QuantifiedConstraints)?

Comment: @illabout This `Tree` type and things like it aren't super common, but existentially-quantified boxes are and need a similar trick. Your link looks closely related, but `Eq1` has the distinct advantage of existing today.

Comment: Tbf, quantified contexts do exist today. They just exist very experimentally.